# How can I get Genesect on Pokemon X & Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

A man in the Fossil Lab asks if I have a Genesect, and if so to bring it to him.

But how how do I get one?

Answer (score 6):

Other than the PokeBank (which will be released in December), *there is currently no way to obtain a Genesect*. There currently have been no hints of a possible Genesect event giveaway, although this does not mean there won't be any in the future.

Comment: Checked in GTS no such pokemon is possible for trade.

Comment: @iber GTS only lists Pokemon you've seen. That won't be until the Pokemon bank opens to transfer gen 5 genesects or a gen 6 event distributes them.

Comment: @BenBrocka Nope. Go to "Pokemon you want" at GTS and scroll down, you will have option "What Pokemon?" where you can manual insert name. I don't have Ekans in my Pokedex but when i writed it down it found trades with it for me :)

Comment: Is there a possibility that you can get Genesect after getting the national pokedex in pokemon x and y??

Comment: @Bosspvz2 doubtful, very many of us have the national pokedex. We'll have to wait for an event or for the pokebank to open.

Comment: Interesting.... I guess that blog I saw was untrue as it said that you can catch any pokemon that has ever existed by getting a national pokedex. @Ben Brocka, thanks for helping.

Comment: Exscuse me for my english, I'm a italian boy.For me it's possible have genesect in pokemon X or Y, because I see a video on a possible red genesect-event.I have pokemon Y, so I hope to find Genesect.